# Remove blank spaces

Tags: ksh

I have an `awk` output which is giving the below output in below format.

`ALTER DISKGROUP +DG_01 DROP FILE '+DG0_1/XYZ/asm_file.123456                ';`
`ALTER DISKGROUP +DG_01 DROP FILE '+DG0_1/XYZ/asm_file.098765                ';`

Is there any way to remove the spaces before `';` ?

It should be as below.

`ALTER DISKGROUP +DG_01 DROP FILE '+DG0_1/XYZ/asm_file.123456';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spaces before `';` with

```
| sed "s/ *';/';/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

from file try:

```
perl -p -e "s/\s*';/';/g" input
```

for replace in place:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/\s*';/';/g" input
```

from awk output:

```
your awk | perl -p -e "s/\s*';/';/g"
```

anyway give us your `awk` to fix it from there avoiding this patch

Comment: `grep -e 'ONLINELOG' ${REDOWORK1}| awk -F / '{dg=$1;gsub("+","",dg); print "ALTER DISKGROUP " dg " DROP FILE !" $0 "!;"}'| \`

Comment: `sed "s/!/'/g"| awk '{print "PROMPT " $0; print $0}'`